# How did the Ashkenazi Yom Tov "prayer mode" become so popular?

Tags: yom-tov, ashkenazi, music, provenance

Since i'm not sure what to call it, a "prayer mode" here is the style of the tunes used. I'm not exactly sure how to describe the tunes. Either you know it or you don't.

The traditional mode for Yom Tov davening among Ashkenazim (at least during the day) seems to have an "amein problem". Namely, the congregation begins saying amen before the chazzan finishes the bracha. This is a problem ([Shulchan Aruch, Orach Chaim 124:8](http://beta.hebrewbooks.org/tursa.aspx?a=oc_x487)).

With this in mind, where did the mode originate, and why is it used so much? Also, did it originally start this way, or has it been corrupted over the years?

FWIW, some chazzanim will cut it short to prevent this problem.

Comment: Any improvements to the title, or clarifying how the mode goes for people unfamiliar would be much appreciated.

Comment: FWIW, I've orened before the amud at schuls where there was no issue with folks saying amen before the end of a bracha or segment of Kaddish. In any case, we know what someone is saying even before the end (e.g. ha-E-l haKa—amen)

Comment: @NoachmiFrankfurt does knowing what the bracha is alleviate the problem?

Comment: I don't know 15

Comment: 1) I don't know about other communities, but I've always heard the tunes referred to as "nusach" which isn't really helpful here since it's easily confused. 2) I've wondered about the "amein problem"  myself before,  and I think it'd be great as its own question (if it doesn't already exist.)

Comment: @NoachmiFrankfurt יש להמתין עד סיום הברכה בטרם אומרים "אמן" - אחרת ה"אמן" נקרא "אמן חטופה

Comment: Is this specifically true by Ashkenazim? Also poskim have already mentioned other points in which they are displeased with chazzanim, even if we assume the basic tunes are from the Maharil, there is no reason to assume it is being presented properly.

Comment: Are you referring to the daytime specifically? I don't think this problem exists at _birchos k'rias "Sh'ma"_ of _maariv_.

Comment: I voted to close for now, because it is unclear if the focus of your question is knowing the history of the common Ashkenaz nusach used for Yom Tov Chazarat Hashat"z or whether using this nusach is problematic b/c of the common early "Amen", which, IMO< is not a problem inherent in the nusach, itself, but a combo of the shat"z's intonation and congregants' "bad" habits. Either way, please clarify what you need to know.

Comment: @Dan I specifically ask about the history. See, it's tagged provenance. I have the halachic concerns planned as another question.